# How to add files recursively to a listbox by selecting a dir in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a list of files to a listbox which follows all sub-directories

Currently I am using the following code however it only searches one directory and does not recurse into subdirectories.

```
  FolderBrowserDialog odd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (odd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {

          string folderName = odd.SelectedPath;
          foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(folderName))
              checkedListBox1.Items.Add(f);
      }
  }
```

Now I modified to this, but says string f doesn't exist in the current code

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(folderName, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
checkedListBox1.Items.Add(f);
```

Comment: So... what happens when you do that?

Comment: Just listing the files from the current folder, but not from the subfolder(s)

Comment: @user830054: Then write it in your question. We can't help you if your question is not complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\CurrentDirectoryName", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Then bind the listbox to that string array

Comment: I tried an other method but doesn't work, with your code crashes.

Comment: What error do you get? I just tested it in a solution and it worked for me :|

Comment: It crashed when tried to add  to the box, but now it's ok, I modified your code to work with mine. Thanks for your help!